# http_negotiate_language issue

Tags: php, lang

Perhaps I missed something but when I call

```
$result='';
      $langs = array(
          'en-US',
          'fr',
       );
var_dump(http_negotiate_language($langs,$result));
```

I have an 500 error message. Should I add some extensions, should I parametrize something on my php.ini ?

Comment: This function is only available if you have `pecl_http` installed. Check your error logs for errors, "500" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: ok thanks sorry not to have been precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is require PECL pecl_http >= 0.1.0